# Pattern match Haskell Higher order function?

Tags: haskell

Imagine I have a custom type and two functions:

```
type MyType = Int -> Bool

f1 :: MyType -> Int
f3 :: MyType -> MyType -> MyType
```

I tried to pattern match as follows:

```
f1 (f3 a b i) = 1
```

But it failed with error: `Parse error in pattern: f1`. What is the proper way to do the above?? Basically, I want to know how many f3 is there (as a and b maybe f3 or some other functions).

Comment: Are you trying to invert a function using pattern matching? If so, this can't feasibly work (and is consequently disallowed in Haskell). What would `f (const 3 x) = x` produce if I evaluated `f 3` ?

Comment: Haskell is a referentially transparent language, which means `f1` can't tell whether its argument came from `f3` or from some other computation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't pattern match on a function. For (almost) any given function, there are an infinite number of ways to define the same function. And it turns out to be mathematically impossible for a computer to always be able to say whether a given definition expresses the same function as another definition. This also means that Haskell would be unable to reliably tell whether a function matches a pattern; so the language simply doesn't allow it.

A pattern must be *either* a single variable *or* a constructor applied to some other patterns. Remembering that constructor start with upper case letters and variables start with lower case letters, your pattern `f3 a n i` is invalid; the "head" of the pattern `f3` is a variable, but it's also applied to `a`, `n`, and `i`. That's the error message you're getting.

Since functions don't have constructors, it follows that the *only* pattern that can match a function is a single variable; that matches all functions (of the right type to be passed to the pattern, anyway). That's how Haskell enforces the "no pattern matching against functions" rule. Basically, in a higher order function there's no way to tell anything at all about the function you've been given *except* to apply it to something and see what it does.

The function `f1` has type `MyType -> Int`. This is equivalent to `(Int -> Bool) -> Int`. So it takes a *single* function argument of type `Int -> Bool`. I would expect an equation for `f1` to look like:

```
f1 f = ...
```

You don't need to "check" whether it's an `Int -> Bool` function by pattern matching; the type *guarantees* that it will be.

You can't tell *which* one it is; but that's generally the whole point of taking a function as an argument (so that the caller can pick *any* function they like knowing that you'll use them all the same way).

I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to know how many f3 is there". `f1` always receives a *single* function, and `f3` is not a function of the right type to be passed to `f1` at all (it's a `MyType -> MyType -> MyType`, not a `MyType`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, it;s really clear and now I understand why I can't do this. Regarding the problem, I have raised another question which make it clearer why I want to count the occurrence of f3. link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997603/haskell-counting-number-of-function-call

Answer (score 4):

Once a function has been applied its syntactic form is lost. There is now way, should I provide you `2 + 3` to distinguish what you get from just `5`. It *could* have arisen from `2 + 3`, or `3 + 2`, or the mere constant `5`.

If you need to capture syntactic structure then you need to work with syntactic structure.

```
data Exp = I Int | Plus Exp Exp

justFive :: Exp
justFive = I 5

twoPlusThree :: Exp
twoPlusThree = I 2 `Plus` I 3

threePlusTwo :: Exp
threePlusTwo = I 2 `Plus` I 3
```

Here the data type `Exp` captures numeric *expressions* and we can pattern match upon them:

```
isTwoPlusThree :: Exp -> Bool
isTwoPlusThree (Plus (I 2) (I 3)) = True
isTwoPlusThree _ = False
```

But wait, why am I distinguishing between "constructors" which I can pattern match on and.... "*other* syntax" which I cannot?

Essentially, constructors are inert. The behavior of `Plus x y` is... to do nothing at all, to merely remain as a box with two slots called "`Plus _ _`" and plug the two slots with the values represented by `x` and `y`.

On the other hand, function application is the furthest thing from inert! When you apply an expression to a function that function `(\x -> ...)` replaces the `x`es within its body with the applied value. This *dynamic reduction* behavior means that there is no way to get a hold of "function applications". They vanish into thing air as soon as you look at them.