# Haskell counting number of function call

Tags: haskell

Say I have a function `concat :: String -> String -> String`. So,

```
var :: String
var = concat (concat "a" "b") "c")  -- "abc"
```

Now, I have a function which I want to use to calculate how many times concat is called:

```
func :: (String->String->String) -> Int
```

So, `func var` should return 2.

How should I get this value and at the same time perform the concat?

Comment: I'm curious - why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Putting aside that `var` has the wrong type, you can't.

Reason 1: You can write exactly the same function as `var` without ever calling `concat`. Assuming the obvious definition of `concat`:

```
var1 = "a" ++ "b" ++ "c"
```

or

```
var2 = "abc"
```

In fact, the compiler will turn your `var` into `var2` when you compile with optimizations!

Reason 2: What if the number of calls to `concat` depends on the arguments? What should

```
func f 
  where f x y = if x == "" then y else (concat x y)
```

return?

Comment: What if the String type becomes a custom type?

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @xcoder You can do this by using custom type which *stores* the function `concat` and the string arguments, instead of actually applying concat. Then you can count the number of concats in that data structure, and separately also ask for the string that would be produced by actually applying concat. That's basically @dfeur's answer. But without having made special arrangements up front, no there's no way to tell what operations were used to come up with a given value (of *any* type).

Comment: @Ben I think thats the key issue. How can you count in the structure w/o actually calling the function? We cannot pattern match =[

Comment: @xcoder: Haskell is pretty deliberately designed so you can't.  That's referential transparency: you can't determine how a value was computed; replacing an expression with its result always preserves behavior.

Answer (score 6):

The right way to do this is to replace `concat :: String -> String -> String` with `concatA :: String -> String -> f (String)`, for some appropriate `Applicative` `f`. For example, you could use `Writer`:

```
concatW :: String -> String -> Writer Int String
concatW s1 s2 = Writer (s1++s2, Sum 1)
```

Now

```
concatW s1 s2 >>= concatW s3 >>= concatW s4
```

Or

```
(<=) <$> concatW s1 s2 <*> concatW s3 s4
```

will count things for you.

---

If you are interested in how many times your function is called for debugging purposes, you may want to use `trace` from `Debug.Trace`. You may also want to use the profiler and annotate the function as a cost center. You could even use `unsafePerformIO` if you're crazy. But these are not things that should generally appear in a released program.